# How to use dplyr to eliminate for loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, spatial, dplyr

Does anyone know of a dplyr method for doing pairwise matching on data with missing observations followed by subsequent arithmetic?  The below for-loop heavy code is a MWE in base, but I couldn't get my arms around a dplyr approach (despite the excellent vignettes and documentation).

In brief, the code calculates `dev`, which is just an average of all the non-missing quantity observations `q` sold at adjacent `adj` stores that week.

EDIT: I'm interested in states with divergent policies.  Let the vertical line below represent the state boundary: counties 1, 2, and 3 are in state A (with policy A), and counties 4, 5, and 6 are in state B (with policy B).  Counties may have multiple stores.

```
----|----
  1 |  4
    |----
----|  5
  2 |
----|----
  3 |  6
----|----
```

`contig.id` identifies a county that is contiguous with one or more counties in the *opposite* state.  For example, county 1 (`contig.id == 1`) is adjacent to counties 4 and 5 in the opposite state (`adj1 == 4` and `adj2 == 5`), where we disregard county 2's geographic adjacency since 1 and 2 are in the same state.

By the same method, county 4 (`contig.id == 4`) is adjacent to county 1 only (`adj1 == 1` and `adj2 == NA`).
End EDIT.

```
df <- data.frame(store     = c(1001,1001,145,331,228,228,500,500,61,1135),
                 end.week  = c(20061125,20061118,20061125,20061125,20061125,
                           20061118,20061125,20061118,20061118,20061125),
                 contig.id = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,NA),
                 adj1      = c(4,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,NA),
                 adj2      = c(5,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA),
                 q         = c(12.25,14.5,18.75,16,16.5,22,55.25,8.25,24,37.75))

dev  <- NULL
dev1 <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(df$contig.id)) {
  temp1 <- integer(0)
  temp2 <- integer(0)
  if (is.na(df$contig.id[i]) == FALSE) {
    temp1 <- which( (df$contig.id == df$adj1[i]) &
                    (df$end.week == df$end.week[i]))
    if (length(temp1) > 0) {
      dev[i] <- sum(df$q[temp1])  
    }
    if (is.na(df$adj2[i]) == FALSE) {
      temp2    <- which( (df$contig.id == df$adj2[i]) &
                         (df$end.week == df$end.week[i]) )
      if (length(temp2) > 0) {
        dev[i] <- dev[i] + sum(df$q[temp2])
      }
    }
  } else {
    dev[i] <- NA
  }
  dev[i]  <- dev[i]/(length(temp1) + length(temp2))
  dev1[i] <- (df$q[i])/dev[i]
}
df <- cbind(df,dev,dev1)
```

Comment: I think it should be possible, but I can't quite get my head around the relationship of adj1, adj2 and contig.id.  Can you explain them in more detail?

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald, the picture in the edit above is how I've been thinking about the relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you actually have three kinds of information here, which is why you needed such complex for-looping.  I've tried to normalize your data into three tables:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

stores_time <- df %>%
  select(-contig.id,-adj1,-adj2)

stores_space <- df %>%
  select(store,contig.id) %>%
  mutate(county = contig.id %>% paste0("c",.)) %>%
  select(-contig.id) %>%
  unique

counties <- df %>%
  select(contig.id,adj1,adj2) %>%
  mutate(county = contig.id %>% paste0("c",.)) %>%
  select(-contig.id) %>%
  unique %>%
  gather(varname,adj_next_state,starts_with("adj")) %>%
  select(-varname) %>%
  mutate(adj_next_state = adj_next_state %>% paste0("c",.))
```

Now we have info on each store's sales over time (`stores_time`), each store's "location" in space (i.e. which county they are in, `stores_space`) and info on the adjacency of the counties (`counties`).  I've also converted the data from wide to long -- which may come in handy, if you have counties which are adjacent to >2 other counties.

We can join all of these together, to obtain a dataset of each store's performance in both "time" and "space":

```
stores_tsc <- stores_time %>%
  left_join(stores_space) %>%
  left_join(counties)
```

To calculate dev, you need to join this table back onto itself.  That is because, for each store x time combination you want to average all the adjacent stores.  so when you join the table to itself, you need to join `county` to `adj_next_state`. We can use some `select` magic to make it easy:

```
stores_tsc %>%
  # rename one column
  select(store,end.week,county = adj_next_state) %>%
  # left join table to itself
  # removing unneeded columns and using unique simply prevents duplicate rows.
  left_join(stores_tsc %>%
              select(-adj_next_state,-store) %>%
              unique,
            by = c("county","end.week")) %>%
  # filter out the store in an unknown county
  filter(county != "cNA") %>%
  # calculate dev
  group_by(store,end.week) %>%
  summarize(dev = mean(q,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(dev = ifelse(is.nan(dev), yes = NA,no = dev))

  store end.week      dev
1    61 20061118 14.50000
2   145 20061125       NA
3   228 20061118 14.50000
4   228 20061125 12.25000
5   331 20061125       NA
6   500 20061118 14.50000
7   500 20061125 12.25000
8  1001 20061118 18.08333
9  1001 20061125 35.87500
```

You could use another merge with `stores_time` to calculate `dev1 = q/dev`

Comment: Thanks!  Not only does this work well, I learned a good deal of dplyr in the process.  Minor question: what is the benefit to writing the counties in character format (i.e. pasting a `c` on the front)?  Is this a syntax habit I should get into?

Comment: @PatW. I'm glad it was helpful! forcing `county` to be character wasn't strictly necessary (`left_join` worked fine with the `end.week` column, which was numeric), but I guess I did it as a reflex, since they represent a category.  It also helps to keep the "NA" from being an actual missing value.  not sure how that would merge!

Comment: @PatW. and, er, if you really did find my answer useful, could you please consider "accepting" it?  (by clicking the checkmark)

Comment: Check.  Also, the gather() approach is really helpful: there are up to 6 adjacent counties in the actual data.

Comment: @PatW.although `reshape2` is also useful, I really like the focused elegance of `tidyr`.

Comment: Oh, and I meant to mention: you might want to check out `lubridate` and/or `tidyr::separate` when you want to start working with those dates :D

Comment: Excellent...lagged prices are next!

Comment: in that case, definitely see `lag` in `dplyr` ;)